# Multiple Lookup Criteria

Tags: excel

I have this data below in Excel. What I want is to return the No.of Inactive months and the Inactive months themselves.

```
              ACTIVITY MONTH
         Jan17 Feb17  Mar17 Apr17 Reg Month No.Inactive months Months Inactive
User ID 
1         5     38     0     60    Jan17
2         0     242    203   20    Feb17
3         30    0       0    30    Jan17
4         0     0       0    40    Apr17
5         0     0      16    0     Mar17
```

Comment: Hi.Bruce I have tried everything if count nothing I just want to know the inactive period and which are these ones is more like a multiple array formulae. can you help??

Answer (score 0):

To count the inactive months you can use the following.

```
+---+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+
|   |  A   |   B    |   C    |   D    |   E    | F|        G        |
+---+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+
| 1 | User | Jan 17 | feb-17 | mar-17 | apr-17 |  | Inactive months |
| 2 | 1    | 5      | 38     | 0      | 60     |  | 1               |
| 3 | 2    | 0      | 242    | 203    | 20     |  | 1               |
| 4 | 3    | 30     | 0      | 0      | 30     |  | 2               |
| 5 | 4    | 0      | 0      | 0      | 40     |  | 3               |
| 6 | 5    | 0      | 0      | 16     | 0      |  | 3               |
+---+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--+-----------------+
```

where in cell G2 the is this formula `=COUNTIF(B2:E2,0)`

To show the list of inactive months it's a little bit harder.

The point is that you have to explain how you want to see these results.

The easier way is to use the conditional formatting anc color the cell with zero (but this is not so useful). Others way could be to traspose the table and filter the column with zero. Another one could be to use a VBA macro....